# How to populate collection of user detail more efficiently

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `Module` class, a `User`, a `UserModule` and a `UserModuleLevel` class.

`_module_objects` is a static `ObservableCollection` of Modules and gets created when the program starts, there's about 10 of them. e.g. User Management, Customer Services, etc.

`User` as you can probably guess is user details: ID, Name, etc. Populated from a db query.

With `UserModules`, I do not keep the module information in the db, just the module level, which is just the module security levels. this is kept in the db as: User_ID, Module_ID, ModuleLevel, ModuleLevelAccess.

What I'm trying to do is populate an `ObservableCollection` of users in the fastest manner. I have about 120,000 users, usually these users only have access to 2 or 3 of the 10 modules.

Below is what I have tried so far, however the piece with asterisks around it is the bottle neck, because it is going through every module of every user.

Hoping for some advice to speed things up.

```cs
public class UserRepository
{
    ObservableCollection<User> m_users = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    public UserRepository(){}

    public void LoadUsers()
    {
        var users = SelectUsers();
        foreach (var u in users)
        {
            m_users.Add(u);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> SelectUsers()
    {
        var userModulesLookup = GetUserModules();
        var userModuleLevelsLookup = GetUserModuleLevels().ToLookup(x => Tuple.Create(x.User_ID, x.Module_ID));

        clsDAL.SQLDBAccess db = new clsDAL.SQLDBAccess("DB_USERS");
        db.setCommandText("SELECT * FROM USERS");
        using (var reader = db.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var user = new User();
                var userId = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "USER_ID");
                user.User_ID = userId;
                user.Username = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader, "USERNAME");
                user.Name = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader, "NAME");
                user.Job_Title = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader, "JOB_TITLE");
                user.Department = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader, "DEPARTMENT");
                user.Company = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader, "COMPANY");
                user.Phone_Office = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader, "PHONE_OFFICE");
                user.Phone_Mobile = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader, "PHONE_MOBILE");
                user.Email = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader, "EMAIL");

                user.UserModules = new ObservableCollection<UserModule>(userModulesLookup);

                //**************** BOTTLENECK **********************************
                foreach (var mod in user.UserModules)
                {
                    mod.UserModuleLevels = new ObservableCollection<UserModuleLevel>(userModuleLevelsLookup[Tuple.Create(userId, mod.Module.Module_ID)]);
                }
                //**************************************************************

                yield return user;
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Users.UserModule> GetUserModules()
    {
        foreach (Module m in ModuleKey._module_objects)
        {
            //Set a reference in the UserModule to the original static module.
            var user_module = new Users.UserModule(m);
            yield return user_module;
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Users.UserModuleLevel> GetUserModuleLevels()
    {
        clsDAL.SQLDBAccess db_user_module_levels = new clsDAL.SQLDBAccess("DB_USERS");
        db_user_module_levels.setCommandText(@"SELECT * FROM USER_MODULE_SECURITY");
        using (var reader = db_user_module_levels.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int u_id = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "USER_ID");
                int m_id = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "MODULE_ID");
                int ml_id = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "MODULE_LEVEL_ID");
                int mla = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "MODULE_LEVEL_ACCESS");

                yield return new Users.UserModuleLevel(u_id, m_id, ml_id, mla);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the end I'll put the users into a DataGrid with module security displayed, buttons with green show there is some type of access to this module, clicking on it will bring up actual security settings.[image]

Comment: How did you define your `USER_MODULE_SECURITY`? if you only store granted module security levels for each user, then when you join `USERS` with `USER_MODULE_SECURITY` you can just work with one table?

Comment: [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization) might help, but requires your efforts because it is a long article.

Comment: Sounds like you could easily get this information in a single query rather than querying for the two tables and using a scissors/glue approach in the application code (SQL can be orders of magnitude faster when glueing things together). How long is this taking to run through the list - and why do you need to process all 120,000 users at once? What about a paging or partial load strategy?

Comment: Example: I've got an app which is written for internal use which brings all of our disparate systems into a single searchable app (you can find customers/suppliers/orders/post timesheets etc). On the search screen you can search for anything in a single search box (clients, orders, support tickets etc) - there are over 32,000 orders, thousands of customers and 400,000 tickets for which the query searches many fields in each object type. These come back in less than a second because I only load a page of 10 at a time - the user doesn't need to see 400,000 rows at once..that's what search is for

Comment: Try using paging - the number of users will likely grow. Then use sql like "SELECT whatever_you_really_need FROM USERS JOIN USER_MODULE_SECURITY ON something" This will speed things up.

Comment: That's great advice thank you, now I know what to look for. Looks a little formidible but will give it go. Love to close this with answer.

Comment: Have you any experience with ORMs such as NHibernate, Entity Framework, OrmLite, Dapper etc? You might want to consider using a lightweight ORM as it makes stuff like this simple enough and gets rid of any hard coded SQL strings (such as the `SELECT * FROM Users` string - (except in the case of Dapper which is super lightweight and sacrifices a query API for speed/terseness)) making things easier to refactor. Also most of them support some sort of paging mechanism via an API, taking the hard work out of writing the same thing directly in SQL statements

Comment: No experience with any ORMs, will check these out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance gains you can do a few things:

- Change your data access code to perform JOINs in SQL to get your data as a single result set.

  SQL tends to be a fair bit faster at returning a result set of relational data than C# is at glueing the data together after the fact. This is because it's optimised to do just that and you should take advantage of that
- You should probably consider paging the results - any user that says they need all 120,000 results at once should be slapped upside the head with a large trout. Paging the results will limit the amount of processing that you need to do in the application

Doing the above can be quite daunting as you would need to modify your application to include paging - often 3rd party controls such as grids etc have some paging mechanisms built in, and these days most ORM software has some sort of paging support which translates your C# code to the correct dialect for your chosen RDBMS

A good example (I've been working with a bit lately) is ServiceStack OrmLite.

I believe it to be free as long as you are using the legacy V3 version (which is pretty darn good .. https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3) and I've seen some forks of it on GitHub which are currently maintained (http://www.nservicekit.com/)

There is a small learning curve, but nothing the examples/docs can't tell you

Here's an extension method I'm using to page my queries in my service layer:

```
public static SqlExpressionVisitor<T> PageByRequest<T>(this SqlExpressionVisitor<T> expr, PagedRequest request)
{
    return expr.Limit((request.PageNumber - 1) * request.PageSize, request.PageSize);
}
```

The request contains the page number and page size (from my web app), and the `Limit` extension method in OrmLite does the rest. I should probably add that the `<T>` generic parameter is the object type that OrmLite will map to after it has queried.

Here's an example of that (its just a POCO with some annotations)

```
[Alias("Customers")]
public class Customer : IHasId<string>
{
    [Alias("AccountCode")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    // ... a load of other fields
}
```

The method is translated to T-SQL and results in the following query against the DB (for this example I selected page 4 on my customer list with a page size of 10):

```
SELECT <A big list of Fields> FROM 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AccountCode) As RowNum, * FROM "Customers") 
AS RowConstrainedResult 
WHERE RowNum > 40 AND RowNum <= 50
```

This keeps the query time down to way less than a second and ensures I don't need to write a shedload of vendor specific SQL

It really depends on how much application you have already got - if you are too far in, it may be a nightmare to refactor for an ORM, but it's worth considering for other projects

Comment: Ok this may be jump a bit too far ahead, however, I was going to implement a multiedit type tool to select a range of users and set user module security on them. This would have been quite simple if I had the users in memory, if I am loading and unloading users is this still possible? I haven't read through much yet but it's the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: You could possibly still load all users - 120,000 records isn't actually that many assuming you are only returning a small number of fields (e.g. username and a couple of rows of permission sets). When you say that your code is slow, how long does it take to complete the build of the user/permission list? It may be that because of the manual crunching in .NET you are seeing a massive efficiency loss

Comment: I will get back to you on that tomorrow with some figures. Midnight in Aussie right now

Comment: I placed a stopwatch on the code. It takes about 36 seconds for everything to load with the code above. If I cut out all the module security and just load the users only, it takes about 3 seconds. User has only 9 fields and the db is SQL Server just run locally for now, but will eventually be on a network.

Comment: I created another question related to this one, as I am curious about editing when using Data Virtualization. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534231/displaying-and-editing-large-datasets-with-data-virtualization     I believe as far as scalability it would be a good idea to implement this but trying to look at the big picture also.

Comment: I'd only look at data virtualization once you know you have a performance issue that isn't avoidable. I can do a demo app that I'm sure I can get loading 120,000 rows of data with associated permissions in less than a couple of seconds - 36 seconds is ridiculously long

Comment: Ok I did a test and thinking about the numbers you are looking at a lot of data - I used Entity Framework to model your database and fetched 131,000 users with 4 module access records each (for a total of over half a million records) in about 15 seconds (bear in mind EF takes about 5/6 seconds to setup the context). I'd seriously consider using pagination and search - surely if you need to set permissions for a bunch of users it will be a bunch of users in the same department/company at the same time? There can't be any reason to need 120,000 records or anything close to that simultaneously

Comment: Ok further testing (bearing in mind cache etc) - it takes about 3/4 seconds to fetch half a million records into a EF entity set after the context has been created for the first time. You might be able to get away with loading the whole lot in one go - but still consider paging (maybe in 1000s?)

Comment: Ok that's exciting. I would be very interested in seeing that project. Is the half million including module access?

Comment: It's 131,000 user records and 4 module access records for each user. I'll post it somewhere with the DB schema, though you will have to generate the data (I made scripts for that)

Comment: Hi Charleh, don't suppose you've posted that project somewhere?

Comment: Hi Hank, I did some more testing and after adding the data to an observable collection the load time increased by a fair bit. It's not 30 seconds but it's close. Paging by 100 or even 1000 at a time was way more acceptable. which 3rd party controls are you using for your grids? Is there paging support and would you like an example project of this?

Comment: Hi Charleh, I'm using a wpf datagrid, I believe most wpf grid types support it. Yes please love to see the project!  Trying to spruce up on my EF so am very interested how you set up the entities.

Comment: Hi Charleh, any luck popping that project up?

Comment: Sorry mate, soon, my week off and i managed to contract tonsillitis on the first day! Will post at some point probably this weekend!

Comment: Oh dear no rush get better first

Comment: Ok I'm back at work and I've opened this project (and yes it's a mess) - but I can post it in a bit. I've used Entity Framework with no paging and lazy loading and the performance is good enough (I am running a decent rig though so your mileage may vary). I'll add a paging example too before I post

Comment: Hi Charleh, so you're back on the karaoke circuit! Mess is fine, don't worry about that, just running through 64bit i7 so it's not running on coal, but we'll see.

Comment: Hi Hank, it's a bit messy but it should show the difference in speed between the different methods. I've not actually added any pagination controls, you have to just manually type the page number/page size. It will only refresh the current tab you have selected and it does so when you change the value in the search box (or if you change the page no/size on the paginated tab). It also requires some data. I've attached the script for the tables I was using, but you will need to create the db and generate some data to fill the tables. http://www.filedropper.com/wpfapplication1

Comment: Oh and some namespaces are a mess as I started with a console project and moved to a WPF one halfway through :) - oh yeah and hopefully NuGet should restore packages as I've not included them (you need entity framework) - if it doesn't you can add them manually from package manager console

Comment: There is a delay on the first access (which is EF setting up the context) but after that, the lazy loaded one is pretty quick considering it isn't paginated in any way. Eager loading is so very much slower and pagination is the fastest but you can't see all the data in a single list. Hopefully it gives you some options

Comment: Oh and finally, the connection string is in the app.config file - you'll need to point that to somewhere sensible, the context uses the connection string called `TestConnection` so don't change the connection name unless you are going to update the `TestContext` class.